# Looping through data attributes to create 4 separate bar charts... why are there "phantom" data elements being bound to the xAxis?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to make a quad chart where each quadrant contains a bar chart depicting different attributes of a set of 5 data objects.  Something like [image: **this**].

The first chart is just as I expect.  The problems are the x-axes of the next three charts.  Somehow, there are "phantom" data elements being bound to the g element created by d3.svg.axis().  In each case the data elements are integers 0-4.
As shown in my code below, I am creating each bar chart within its own svg and I am defining everything I can within a loop where I loop over the list of attributes I want to plot.  The reason I am doing this is that my full data set has around 20 attributes per object, but I only want to plot 4 at a time.  Also, I don't want to repeat code that only differs by one parameter.

But I suspect it is something within the forEach loop and the xAxis function causing the problem.

Here is my entire js file:

```
var data = [{"name": "A", "engine_size": "1.6", "cmpg": "28", "horsepower": "103",  "msrp": "11690"}, 
{"name": "B", "engine_size": "1.6", "cmpg": "28", "horsepower": "103", "msrp": "12585"},
{"name": "C", "engine_size": "2.2", "cmpg": "26", "horsepower": "140", "msrp": "14610"}, 
{"name": "D",  "engine_size": "2.2", "cmpg": "26", "horsepower": "140", "msrp": "14810"},
{"name": "E",  "engine_size": "2.2", "cmpg": "26",  "horsepower": "140", "msrp": "16385"}];

var outer_width = 330,
    outer_height = 200,
    margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10},
    padding = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20},
    inner_width = outer_width - margin.left - margin.right,
    inner_height = outer_height - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    width = inner_width - padding.left - padding.right,
    height = inner_height - padding.top - padding.bottom;

var key = function(d) {
    return d.name;
}

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0.05);

var color = d3.scale.category20c();

var attribute_list = ['msrp', 'engine_size', 'horsepower', 'cmpg']; 
var svg = {};
attribute_list.forEach(function(entry) {
    svg[entry] = d3.select('.' + entry).append('svg')
    .attr('width', outer_width)
    .attr('height', outer_height)
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ', ' + margin.top + ')');
});

//d3.json('data/cars.json', function(error, data) {
    x.domain(data.map(key));
    xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient('bottom')
        .ticks(data.length);

    attribute_list.forEach(function(entry) {
        var g = svg[entry].append('g')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(0, ' + margin.bottom + ')')
            .append('g')
            .attr('class', 'axis')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(0, ' + height + ')')
            .call(xAxis);

        console.log(g.selectAll('line'));

        var y = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([d3.min(data, function(d) { return +d[entry]; }),
                  d3.max(data, function(d) { return +d[entry]; })])
            .range([height*0.2, height*0.8]);   

        var bars = svg[entry].selectAll('rect')
            .data(data, key)
            .enter();

        bars.append('rect')
            .attr('class', 'bar')
            .attr('height', function(d) { return y(+d[entry]); })
            .attr('width', function(d) { return x.rangeBand(); })
            .attr('x', function(d, i) { return x(i); })
            .attr('y', function(d) { return height-y(+d[entry]); })
            .attr("fill", function(d){ return color(key(d)); });    
    }); 
//});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure where you're getting that output from, as the code you've provided doesn't create that output.

Snippet of your code here:

```js
var data = [{"name": "A", "engine_size": "1.6", "cmpg": "28", "horsepower": "103",  "msrp": "11690"}, 
{"name": "B", "engine_size": "1.6", "cmpg": "28", "horsepower": "103", "msrp": "12585"},
{"name": "C", "engine_size": "2.2", "cmpg": "26", "horsepower": "140", "msrp": "14610"}, 
{"name": "D",  "engine_size": "2.2", "cmpg": "26", "horsepower": "140", "msrp": "14810"},
{"name": "E",  "engine_size": "2.2", "cmpg": "26",  "horsepower": "140", "msrp": "16385"}];

var outer_width = 330,
    outer_height = 200,
    margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10},
    padding = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20},
    inner_width = outer_width - margin.left - margin.right,
    inner_height = outer_height - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    width = inner_width - padding.left - padding.right,
    height = inner_height - padding.top - padding.bottom;

var key = function(d) {
    return d.name;
}

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0.05);

var color = d3.scale.category20c();

var attribute_list = ['msrp', 'engine_size', 'horsepower', 'cmpg']; 
var svg = {};
attribute_list.forEach(function(entry) {
    svg[entry] = d3.select('.' + entry).append('svg')
    .attr('width', outer_width)
    .attr('height', outer_height)
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ', ' + margin.top + ')');
});

//d3.json('data/cars.json', function(error, data) {
    x.domain(data.map(key));
    xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient('bottom')
        .ticks(data.length);

    attribute_list.forEach(function(entry) {
        var g = svg[entry].append('g')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(0, ' + margin.bottom + ')')
            .append('g')
            .attr('class', 'axis')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(0, ' + height + ')')
            .call(xAxis);

        console.log(g.selectAll('line'));

        var y = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([d3.min(data, function(d) { return +d[entry]; }),
                  d3.max(data, function(d) { return +d[entry]; })])
            .range([height*0.2, height*0.8]);   

        var bars = svg[entry].selectAll('rect')
            .data(data, key)
            .enter();

        bars.append('rect')
            .attr('class', 'bar')
            .attr('height', function(d) { return y(+d[entry]); })
            .attr('width', function(d) { return x.rangeBand(); })
            .attr('x', function(d, i) { return x(i); })
            .attr('y', function(d) { return height-y(+d[entry]); })
            .attr("fill", function(d){ return color(key(d)); });    
    }); 
//});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="msrp"></div>
<div class="engine_size"></div>
<div class="horsepower"></div>
<div class="cmpg"></div>
```

That is your code and it seemingly produces a single bar left aligned on each graph, and the `X` axis looks to be labelled correctly.  Each chart actually contains five bars, but they overlap.

Here is some corrected code:

```js
var data = [{"name": "A", "engine_size": "1.6", "cmpg": "28", "horsepower": "103",  "msrp": "11690"}, 
{"name": "B", "engine_size": "1.6", "cmpg": "28", "horsepower": "103", "msrp": "12585"},
{"name": "C", "engine_size": "2.2", "cmpg": "26", "horsepower": "140", "msrp": "14610"}, 
{"name": "D",  "engine_size": "2.2", "cmpg": "26", "horsepower": "140", "msrp": "14810"},
{"name": "E",  "engine_size": "2.2", "cmpg": "26",  "horsepower": "140", "msrp": "16385"}];


var outer_width = 330,
    outer_height = 200,
    margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10},
    padding = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20},
    inner_width = outer_width - margin.left - margin.right,
    inner_height = outer_height - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    width = inner_width - padding.left - padding.right,
    height = inner_height - padding.top - padding.bottom;

var key = function(d) {
    return d.name;
}

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0.05);

var color = d3.scale.category20c();

var attribute_list = ['msrp', 'engine_size', 'horsepower', 'cmpg']; 
var svg = {};
attribute_list.forEach(function(entry) {
    svg[entry] = d3.select('.' + entry).append('svg')
    .attr('width', outer_width)
    .attr('height', outer_height)
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ', ' + margin.top + ')');
});

//d3.json('data/cars.json', function(error, data) {
    x.domain(data.map(key));
    xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient('bottom')
        .ticks(data.length);

    attribute_list.forEach(function(entry) {
        var g = svg[entry].append('g')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(0, ' + margin.bottom + ')')
            .append('g')
            .attr('class', 'axis')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(0, ' + height + ')')
            .call(xAxis);

        console.log(g.selectAll('line'));

        var y = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([d3.min(data, function(d) { return +d[entry]; }),
                  d3.max(data, function(d) { return +d[entry]; })])
            .range([height*0.2, height*0.8]);   

        var bars = svg[entry].selectAll('rect')
            .data(data, key)
            .enter();

        bars.append('rect')
            .attr('class', 'bar')
            .attr('height', function(d) { return y(+d[entry]); })
            .attr('width', function(d) { return x.rangeBand(); })
            .attr('x', function(d, i) { return x(d.name); })
            .attr('y', function(d) { return height-y(+d[entry]); })
            .attr("fill", function(d){ return color(key(d)); });    
    }); 
//});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="msrp"></div>
<div class="engine_size"></div>
<div class="horsepower"></div>
<div class="cmpg"></div>
```

You were calculating your `X` position for each bar with:

```
.attr('x', function(d, i) { return x(i); })
```

I think you actually wanted to calculate your `X` position for each bar with:

```
.attr('x', function(d, i) { return x(d.name); })
```

You were passing in the index, which is not a part of the domain defined for the `X` scale, which will return undefined.  Passing in the name means that you're passing in a value that's part of the domain so you'll get a corresponding co-ordinate back.

Comment: Thank you.  That was the perfect fix.  An interesting note about the output I showed above:  I was using D3 version 3.2.8, which generates that output (bars as expected but a messed up axis), while version 3.4.11 generates the 'overlapping bar' chart you described with no unexpected result in the axis.

In any case, the error was exactly as you described.  It was just unfortunate that the version I was using had `x(i)` return the expected `x` position rather than defaulting to the first position since I was 'out of domain'.

Comment: Since this one was answered, we've also had http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28491838/d3-js-how-to-draw-stacked-horziontal-bars-from-array/28492240#28492240 which is a slightly different issue, but seemingly related.

Comment: Double thumbs up for this great explanation and solution. I've been searching for this for an hour and you nailed it ! If I could upvote twice, I would :D