# d3.js How to draw stacked horziontal bars from array?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to get this particular example of stacked horizontal bars to work in a browser standalone: http://tributary.io/inlet/4966973 . I know a question has been asked about this code before, but it was never taken to a working example. When I run the code below in a browser (ie outside the tributary site), I get this error:
'Error: Invalid value for  attribute transform="translate(0,NaN)"'. Why won't the code run in a browser? Is there some element missing?

```
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

<section id="display" style="width: 1038px;">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" class="tributary_svg" width="677" height="533"></svg></section>
</div>
<script>
/*modified from Mike Bostock at http://bl.ocks.org/3943967 */

var data = [
{"key":"FL", "pop1":3000, "pop2":4000, "pop3":5000},
{"key":"CA", "pop1":3000, "pop2":3000, "pop3":3000},
{"key":"NY", "pop1":12000, "pop2":5000, "pop3":13000},
{"key":"NC", "pop1":8000, "pop2":21000, "pop3":11000},
{"key":"SC", "pop1":30000, "pop2":12000, "pop3":8000},
{"key":"AZ", "pop1":26614, "pop2":6944, "pop3":30778},
{"key":"TX", "pop1":8000, "pop2":12088, "pop3":20000}
];

var n = 3, // number of layers
m = data.length, // number of samples per layer
stack = d3.layout.stack(),
labels = data.map(function(d) {return d.key;}),

//go through each layer (pop1, pop2 etc, that's the range(n) part)
//then go through each object in data and pull out that objects's population data
//and put it into an array where x is the index and y is the number
layers = stack(d3.range(n).map(function(d) { 
            var a = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
                a[i] = {x: i, y: data[i]['pop' + (d+1)]};  
            }
            return a;
         })),

//the largest single layer
yGroupMax = d3.max(layers, function(layer) { return d3.max(layer,      function(d) { return d.y; }); }),
//the largest stack
yStackMax = d3.max(layers, function(layer) { return d3.max(layer, function(d) { return d.y0 + d.y; }); });

var margin = {top: 40, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 50},
width = 677 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 533 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
.domain(d3.range(m))
.rangeRoundBands([2, height], .08);

var x = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([0, yStackMax])
.range([0, width]);

var color = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([0, n - 1])
.range(["#aad", "#556"]);

var xx = margin.top;

var svg = d3.select("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var layer = svg.selectAll(".layer")
.data(layers)
.enter().append("g")
.attr("class", "layer")
.style("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); });

 layer.selectAll("rect")
.data(function(d) { return d; })
.enter().append("rect")
.attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.x); })
.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.y0); })
.attr("height", y.rangeBand())
.attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.y); });

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(y)
.tickSize(1)
.tickPadding(6)
.tickValues(labels)
.orient("left");

svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "y axis")
.call(yAxis);
</script

    </body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've found yourself a rather interesting issue, and it may be related to what we found with another similar problem.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26029141/looping-through-data-attributes-to-create-4-separate-bar-charts-why-are-there/26030896#26030896).

To test the theory, here is your code copy and pasted into Stack Overflow snippets.  The first one is using d3 3.2.8, and seems to work properly.

```js
/*modified from Mike Bostock at http://bl.ocks.org/3943967 */

var data = [
{"key":"FL", "pop1":3000, "pop2":4000, "pop3":5000},
{"key":"CA", "pop1":3000, "pop2":3000, "pop3":3000},
{"key":"NY", "pop1":12000, "pop2":5000, "pop3":13000},
{"key":"NC", "pop1":8000, "pop2":21000, "pop3":11000},
{"key":"SC", "pop1":30000, "pop2":12000, "pop3":8000},
{"key":"AZ", "pop1":26614, "pop2":6944, "pop3":30778},
{"key":"TX", "pop1":8000, "pop2":12088, "pop3":20000}
];

var n = 3, // number of layers
m = data.length, // number of samples per layer
stack = d3.layout.stack(),
labels = data.map(function(d) {return d.key;}),

//go through each layer (pop1, pop2 etc, that's the range(n) part)
//then go through each object in data and pull out that objects's population data
//and put it into an array where x is the index and y is the number
layers = stack(d3.range(n).map(function(d) { 
            var a = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
                a[i] = {x: i, y: data[i]['pop' + (d+1)]};  
            }
            return a;
         })),

//the largest single layer
yGroupMax = d3.max(layers, function(layer) { return d3.max(layer,      function(d) { return d.y; }); }),
//the largest stack
yStackMax = d3.max(layers, function(layer) { return d3.max(layer, function(d) { return d.y0 + d.y; }); });

var margin = {top: 40, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 50},
width = 677 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 533 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
.domain(d3.range(m))
.rangeRoundBands([2, height], .08);

var x = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([0, yStackMax])
.range([0, width]);

var color = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([0, n - 1])
.range(["#aad", "#556"]);

var xx = margin.top;

var svg = d3.select("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var layer = svg.selectAll(".layer")
.data(layers)
.enter().append("g")
.attr("class", "layer")
.style("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); });

 layer.selectAll("rect")
.data(function(d) { return d; })
.enter().append("rect")
.attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.x); })
.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.y0); })
.attr("height", y.rangeBand())
.attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.y); });

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(y)
.tickSize(1)
.tickPadding(6)
.tickValues(labels)
.orient("left");

svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "y axis")
.call(yAxis);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.2.8/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

<section id="display" style="width: 1038px;">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" class="tributary_svg" width="677" height="533"></svg></section>
</div>
```

Here it is again, this time using d3 3.4.11

```js
/*modified from Mike Bostock at http://bl.ocks.org/3943967 */

var data = [
{"key":"FL", "pop1":3000, "pop2":4000, "pop3":5000},
{"key":"CA", "pop1":3000, "pop2":3000, "pop3":3000},
{"key":"NY", "pop1":12000, "pop2":5000, "pop3":13000},
{"key":"NC", "pop1":8000, "pop2":21000, "pop3":11000},
{"key":"SC", "pop1":30000, "pop2":12000, "pop3":8000},
{"key":"AZ", "pop1":26614, "pop2":6944, "pop3":30778},
{"key":"TX", "pop1":8000, "pop2":12088, "pop3":20000}
];

var n = 3, // number of layers
m = data.length, // number of samples per layer
stack = d3.layout.stack(),
labels = data.map(function(d) {return d.key;}),

//go through each layer (pop1, pop2 etc, that's the range(n) part)
//then go through each object in data and pull out that objects's population data
//and put it into an array where x is the index and y is the number
layers = stack(d3.range(n).map(function(d) { 
            var a = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
                a[i] = {x: i, y: data[i]['pop' + (d+1)]};  
            }
            return a;
         })),

//the largest single layer
yGroupMax = d3.max(layers, function(layer) { return d3.max(layer,      function(d) { return d.y; }); }),
//the largest stack
yStackMax = d3.max(layers, function(layer) { return d3.max(layer, function(d) { return d.y0 + d.y; }); });

var margin = {top: 40, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 50},
width = 677 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 533 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
.domain(d3.range(m))
.rangeRoundBands([2, height], .08);

var x = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([0, yStackMax])
.range([0, width]);

var color = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([0, n - 1])
.range(["#aad", "#556"]);

var xx = margin.top;

var svg = d3.select("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var layer = svg.selectAll(".layer")
.data(layers)
.enter().append("g")
.attr("class", "layer")
.style("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); });

 layer.selectAll("rect")
.data(function(d) { return d; })
.enter().append("rect")
.attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.x); })
.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.y0); })
.attr("height", y.rangeBand())
.attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.y); });

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(y)
.tickSize(1)
.tickPadding(6)
.tickValues(labels)
.orient("left");

svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "y axis")
.call(yAxis);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

<section id="display" style="width: 1038px;">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" class="tributary_svg" width="677" height="533"></svg></section>
</div>
```

The javascript is identical between the two snippets, and you can plainly see that the behavior is different.  So, in short, there is a difference between the way that d3 versions handle the y axis (and in particular the domain attached to the axis).

Here's a version that fixes things up in d3 3.4.11

```js
/*modified from Mike Bostock at http://bl.ocks.org/3943967 */

var data = [
{"key":"FL", "pop1":3000, "pop2":4000, "pop3":5000},
{"key":"CA", "pop1":3000, "pop2":3000, "pop3":3000},
{"key":"NY", "pop1":12000, "pop2":5000, "pop3":13000},
{"key":"NC", "pop1":8000, "pop2":21000, "pop3":11000},
{"key":"SC", "pop1":30000, "pop2":12000, "pop3":8000},
{"key":"AZ", "pop1":26614, "pop2":6944, "pop3":30778},
{"key":"TX", "pop1":8000, "pop2":12088, "pop3":20000}
];

var n = 3, // number of layers
m = data.length, // number of samples per layer
stack = d3.layout.stack(),
labels = data.map(function(d) {return d.key;}),

//go through each layer (pop1, pop2 etc, that's the range(n) part)
//then go through each object in data and pull out that objects's population data
//and put it into an array where x is the index and y is the number
layers = stack(d3.range(n).map(function(d) { 
            var a = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
                //a[i] = {x: i, y: data[i]['pop' + (d+1)]};  
                a[i] = {x: data[i].key, y: data[i]['pop' + (d+1)]};  
            }
            return a;
         })),

//the largest single layer
yGroupMax = d3.max(layers, function(layer) { return d3.max(layer,      function(d) { return d.y; }); }),
//the largest stack
yStackMax = d3.max(layers, function(layer) { return d3.max(layer, function(d) { return d.y0 + d.y; }); });

var margin = {top: 40, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 50},
width = 677 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 533 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
//.domain(d3.range(m))
.domain(labels)
.rangeRoundBands([2, height], .08);

var x = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([0, yStackMax])
.range([0, width]);

var color = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([0, n - 1])
.range(["#aad", "#556"]);

var xx = margin.top;

var svg = d3.select("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var layer = svg.selectAll(".layer")
.data(layers)
.enter().append("g")
.attr("class", "layer")
.style("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); });

 layer.selectAll("rect")
.data(function(d) { return d; })
.enter().append("rect")
.attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.x); })
.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.y0); })
.attr("height", y.rangeBand())
.attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.y); });

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(y)
.tickSize(1)
.tickPadding(6)
//.tickValues(labels)
.orient("left");

svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "y axis")
.call(yAxis);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

<section id="display" style="width: 1038px;">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" class="tributary_svg" width="677" height="533"></svg></section>
</div>
```

There are three differences in this version:

1. Update the way the `x` value in the stack is referenced

   ```
   layers = stack(d3.range(n).map(function(d) { 
       var a = [];
           for (var i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
               //a[i] = {x: i, y: data[i]['pop' + (d+1)]};  
               a[i] = {x: data[i].key, y: data[i]['pop' + (d+1)]};  
           }
           return a;
    })),
   ```
2. Change the domain for the `y` scale

   ```
   var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
                   //.domain(d3.range(m))
                  .domain(labels)
                  .rangeRoundBands([2, height], .08);
   ```
3. Remove the `.tickValues` call from the y axis.  It will use the `domain` of the scale instead.

   ```
   var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                     .scale(y)
                     .tickSize(1)
                     .tickPadding(6)
                     //.tickValues(labels)
                     .orient("left");
   ```

You can see that this new version works properly in d3 3.4.11.

Here is the fixed version using d3 3.2.8:

```js
/*modified from Mike Bostock at http://bl.ocks.org/3943967 */

var data = [
{"key":"FL", "pop1":3000, "pop2":4000, "pop3":5000},
{"key":"CA", "pop1":3000, "pop2":3000, "pop3":3000},
{"key":"NY", "pop1":12000, "pop2":5000, "pop3":13000},
{"key":"NC", "pop1":8000, "pop2":21000, "pop3":11000},
{"key":"SC", "pop1":30000, "pop2":12000, "pop3":8000},
{"key":"AZ", "pop1":26614, "pop2":6944, "pop3":30778},
{"key":"TX", "pop1":8000, "pop2":12088, "pop3":20000}
];

var n = 3, // number of layers
m = data.length, // number of samples per layer
stack = d3.layout.stack(),
labels = data.map(function(d) {return d.key;}),

//go through each layer (pop1, pop2 etc, that's the range(n) part)
//then go through each object in data and pull out that objects's population data
//and put it into an array where x is the index and y is the number
layers = stack(d3.range(n).map(function(d) { 
            var a = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
                //a[i] = {x: i, y: data[i]['pop' + (d+1)]};  
                a[i] = {x: data[i].key, y: data[i]['pop' + (d+1)]};  
            }
            return a;
         })),

//the largest single layer
yGroupMax = d3.max(layers, function(layer) { return d3.max(layer,      function(d) { return d.y; }); }),
//the largest stack
yStackMax = d3.max(layers, function(layer) { return d3.max(layer, function(d) { return d.y0 + d.y; }); });

var margin = {top: 40, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 50},
width = 677 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 533 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
//.domain(d3.range(m))
.domain(labels)
.rangeRoundBands([2, height], .08);

var x = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([0, yStackMax])
.range([0, width]);

var color = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([0, n - 1])
.range(["#aad", "#556"]);

var xx = margin.top;

var svg = d3.select("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var layer = svg.selectAll(".layer")
.data(layers)
.enter().append("g")
.attr("class", "layer")
.style("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); });

 layer.selectAll("rect")
.data(function(d) { return d; })
.enter().append("rect")
.attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.x); })
.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.y0); })
.attr("height", y.rangeBand())
.attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.y); });

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(y)
.tickSize(1)
.tickPadding(6)
//.tickValues(labels)
.orient("left");

svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "y axis")
.call(yAxis);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.2.8/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

<section id="display" style="width: 1038px;">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" class="tributary_svg" width="677" height="533"></svg></section>
</div>
```

It also seems to work OK in d3 3.2.8, so it should solve your issues.

It's a fun one to diagnose, and the only thing I can think of is that tributary.io is based on an older version of d3, where the axis/domain interaction was working OK (albeit broken) and in your standalone version, you were referencing the latest version, which has fixed what ever the issue was (resulting in a broken visualisation, since your code depended on it).

Note: it was fun figuring this one out, but without the additional comments in my answer on [26029141](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26029141/looping-through-data-attributes-to-create-4-separate-bar-charts-why-are-there/26030896#26030896) it would have been near impossible to diagnose.

Comment: Had not occurred to me to look at d3 versions. Nice catch!

Comment: Double thumbs up for this great explanation and solution. I've been searching for this for an hour and you nailed it ! If I could upvote twice, I would :D